# Clojure + stomp + websockets

Tags: clojure, websocket, stomp

I have followed a couple of tutorials about interactive/real-time applications using STOMP over WebSockets with the Spring framework using the messaging layer.

[Example in Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

I would like to implement the same functionality in clojure. Has anybody experience in implementing a similar application? I have been looking for documentation/examples about using these technologies, but there is nothing like the examples in clojure.

That it makes sense? Is it necessary to have an external message broker to connect the backend app and the browser clients?

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience using a broker to pass messages along.  However, I think it's still best to write your own http frontend for the browser to talk to.  That frontend in turn can post messages to a broker (using Stomp or any other protocol).  That way, you have more control and you're not tied to a message broker.  For instance you can have the frontend do more than just websockets, like serve static files, or a regular HTTP interface.

But that's up to you, if the broker supports websockets, you can use that too (see for instance [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html)).  My advice is: try the simplest possible way first :-).

Take a look at [Http-kit](http://www.http-kit.org/server.html#websocket) for a good Clojure webserver.  It also has good websocket support.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in having backend app to handle websocket logic, and also a REST endpoint for external apps (mobile). The thing is that I want to made changes in a mobile app and de browser client must receive that changes, in that case the MessageBroker solution of Spring match very good, in the case of doing with clojure I'm not pretty sure how to connect both all clients (thinking in a elastic enviroment). I'm gonna check the http-kit, Thanks a lot!